# BufferedReader readLine returns strange characters

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read JSON data from a URL and I'm getting a very strange behaviour.
I have a ExpandableListView, and every item has a button to recover online data.
The first time you click the button, it works perfectly, but any attempt subsequent fails.
In these attempts, the method readLine returns weird characters:

��������������Y�o�F�W<��2e=�P��Hω/͹���mKr)nEr�ݥ%��ޙ!)R�[��w������<����Le:O��i��&N�9!�D�T�171�<�ej���e��Wք*��8�0��n�R���,��/`(+�D�%�D����'���"��

I can't understand why it only works the very first time.
Even weirder is the fact that it happens on the physical devices, but not on the emulator.
My code is:

```
    public static String readContents(String url) {
        HttpURLConnection con = getConnection(url);
        if (con==null)
            return null;
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8192);
            String tmp;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
            while((tmp = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(tmp).append("\n");
            br.close();
            return sb.toString();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.d("READ FAILED", e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote my code using Apache's EntityUtils and now it's working:

```
    static String response = null;

    public static String readContents(String url) {
      try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("READ FAILED", e.toString());
        return null;
      }
      return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you call

```
con.disconnect();
```

in a `finally` block at the end to close the connection, otherwise you'll end up with lots of connections open that you're not using. It's possible that's causing problems.

Also a bit of

```
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
```

and

```
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

wouldn't go amiss.

You should also be checking the value of `conn.getResponseCode()` to see if the server is returning an error. Anything between `200` and `299` is a success code.

Comment: Thanks, I added the disconnect, but with no luck. And I'm getting a 200 code.

Comment: @droideparanoico I've updated the answer with another couple of things you probably should be doing. Have you thought about echoing the returned string to the logcat? That will help you distinguish between a problem with the HTTP retrieval, and a problem with the display of the returned string.

Comment: Same negative results. It's not a display problem, because the returned data are parsed to a JSONArray, and when it returns these strange characters, I get the error:
"org.json.JSONException: Value ��������������WYo�8�+�¢H��eYq��(Is of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray"
Anyway, I've just echoed the string to the logcat and confirmed it.

Comment: Can you post the raw string data as bytes? Something like `Arrays.toString(thestring.getBytes())` should do it.

Comment: Sure, there you go: http://pastebin.com/ms9MeMXu
Here I've noticed something important, I used [this](http://tools.thebuzzmedia.com/bytechar) Byte/Char converter, and the data seems correct! I can't understand it...

Comment: OK, looks like a charset encoding thing, then. I've added something about that in the answer too. (Also maybe change `UTF8` to `UTF-8` in your `InputStreamReader` line.)

Comment: Bad news, it gets weirder, the correct raw string data I've posted before is the result of had wiped the app data on the android settings, so cliking in an item reacts like the first time. How this relates to a HttpURLConnection? I don't know. This is the data I'm getting now: http://pastebin.com/8J1zfnqj

Comment: Hmm, no idea! You might try capturing the HTTP headers to see if there's anything weird in there, and to see what charset it's claiming to use.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended by rewriting my code to get rid of the mysterious BufferedReader as you can see below ;)